# Extended Queesion on "how to refer subclass variable without declaring that variable in parent class?"

Tags: java, oop, inheritance, polymorphism, abstract

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(final String[] args) {
    B b = new B();
    System.out.println(b);
    }
}

interface MyInterface<T> {
    int getX();
}

abstract class A implements MyInterface {
    @Override
    public String toString() {
    return String.valueOf(getX());
    }
}

class B extends A, implements MyInterface<C> {
    private static final int X = 10;

    @Override
    public int getX() {
    return X;
    }
}

class C  {
    // This is concrete class some 
}
```

I am unable to enhance this interface with generic.
It is throwing error either at abstract class or at implementation class.
How do I make it possible?

Comment: Does above code even compile? Its really unclear what is the problem?

Comment: Why does your interface have a type parameter `T` if you're never going to use it?  What's the point?  I cannot tell what you're trying to accomplish.  "Enhance this interface with generic" tells me nothing.

Comment: I am going to use that T.  I have not shown that details to simplify my question

Comment: I am getting error. The interface MyInterface cannot be implemented more than once with different arguments: MyInterface and MyInterface<C>.
Idea is I need to use/call the implementation of getX() in A.
That is why I need to implement MyInterface in A

Comment: It doesn't simplify the question, it makes it impossible to answer.  Your question is, "How do I make it possible?"--and I have no idea what you're trying to make possible, because you've simplified all the important information out of your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public class MyTest2 {
    public static void main(final String[] args) {
    B b = new B();
    System.out.println(b);
    }
}

interface MyInterface<T> {
    int getX();
}

abstract class A<T> implements MyInterface {
    @Override
    public String toString() {
    return String.valueOf(getX());
    }
}

class B extends A<C>  {
    private static final int X = 10;

    @Override
    public int getX() {
    return X;
    }
}

class C  {
    // This is concrete class some
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean something like this?

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        MyInterface b = new B();
        System.out.println(b);
    }
}

interface MyInterface<T> {
    T getX();
}

abstract class A<T> implements MyInterface {
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return String.valueOf(getX());
    }
}

class B extends A {
    //private static final int X = 10;
    private static final double X = 10;

    //@Override
    public Double getX() {
        return X;
    }
}
```